# Setting PYTHONPATH isn't fixing the "specified object is not a function or found along sys.path" error with pdb in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I'm trying to set up the pdb debugger with IPython in VS Code. I know VS Code has its own debugging system, but I like the pdb / IPython system. It sort of works, but when I try to instantiate a new variable.

I'm opening the anaconda terminal first, and then opening vs code to ensure my conda environment is being used. When I print the os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] variable, it contains both the /anaconda3/envs/myenv folder, as well as the folder containing the currently running *.py file.

I am running the following simple python script:

```
a = 3
breakpoint()
b = 5
```

And then when pdb successfully starts up at line 2, if I try to assign "b = 3", then I get an error, "The specified object "= 3" is not a function or was not found along sys.path."

I'm a bit perplexed by this, because I did google / try to modify my PYTHONPATH to include all of the relevant modules. I was wondering if there's something else I have to do...?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that "b" is the abbreviation of "[break](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break)" (set breakpoint) in the "pdb" debugging command, so please use other variable names:

[image]

In addition, the [debugging function](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_basic-debugging) provided by the "Python" extension is very convenient and worthy of being used. It is recommended that you try to use this function in VS Code.

[image]

Reference: [pdb — The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#module-pdb).